# How to convert String to Date in android programming

Tags: android

In my application I have some strings for show date such as this : **2023-1-5**. 
But I want convert this to **2023-01-05**. 
I know I can check this with `if` condition and when under 10 add 0 to numbers! 
But I want use best way for this and automatically, not with if condition. 
How can I it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String date ="2023-1-5";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String dateNew = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dateNew);
```